# Changing the enabling to disabling content by giving condition to combo box

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have a certain selection in combo box. Based on that selection some items need to be enabled/disabled. However I am unable to do so. And also another problem is once a single option is selected I cant change it to another selection without backspace and typing that selection again.

`m_d_lvlayers` is the variable of IDC of combo box. Its type is `CString`.

```cpp
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnSelchangeLvLayers()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
if (m_d_lvlayers == "2" )
{
    UpdateData();
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(0);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(0);
            //etc etc

    UpdateData(0);
}
else if (m_d_lvlayers == "3")
{
    UpdateData();
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
            //etc etc

    UpdateData(0);
}
else
{
    UpdateData();
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(1);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(1);
    //etc etc

    UpdateData(0);
}

}
```

I expect to get proper selections in combobox and corresponding enabling and disabling.

Comment: You need to call `UpdateData(TRUE);` first to update the variable with the contents of the combo box.

Comment: Also, consider a more modern GUI framework if this is new project. WinForms, Qt, etc.

Comment: I suggest you split your secondary question out as another distinct issue with a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The secondary question was dependent on the first one. The UpdateData(FALSE) or UpdateData(0) causes freezing of combobox and I am unable to select any other value (eg. 3 or 4) once I make one selection (eg 2)

Comment: [Dialog Data Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange) explains, how the system you are trying to use works.

Comment: @IInspectable Dialog Data Exchange explains transfer of dialog items to variables, but I could'nt find help on UpdateData() in a single click for my current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`UpdateData(TRUE);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#updatedata) **first**.

> *bSaveAndValidate*
>
> Flag that indicates whether dialog box is being initialized (FALSE) or **data is being retrieved** (TRUE)

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCbnSelchangeLvLayers()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE); // Controls to Variables

    if (m_d_lvlayers == "2" )
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        //etc etc
    
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
    else if (m_d_lvlayers == "3")
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
                //etc etc
    
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
    else
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_CU)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_LV3_ICI)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        //etc etc
    
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
}
```

Although in your code it makes no sense to call `UpdateData(FALSE);` because all you are doing is setting the control window state to enabled.

Comment: The typical problem I am facing after removing UpdateData(FALSE) is when I select 2 all the windows are enabled. When I select 3 after 2 the windows get disabled. But when I select 3 first then all windows are enabled. So the conditions are following a sequence rather than. Any first selection causes all windows enabled and following selection causes to disable windows accordingly.

Comment: Additionally, On removing UpdateData(TRUE), no items are disabled and the code jumps to the else loop on adding breakpoints.

Comment: Without seeing your complete dialog resource and enough code to reproduce the issue we can’t really help you further.

Comment: Which section of the code would you like to see?? As mentioned earlier UpdateData(TRUE) causes freezing of the combobox and I cannot make any other selection. Moreover I have to make the same selection twice in order to enable or disable dependent items. Kindly help me please as I have not been able to find the solution yet.